# Adding a vertical line to Pandas subplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-science

I am trying to add a vertical line to a Pandas.dataframe.plot(subplot), but am struggling big time. Current Code:

```
df_final = df_final / df_final.max(axis=0)
df_final.loc[30102040].plot(subplots=True, layout=(17, 1), figsize=(25, 25), sharex=True, sharey=True)
plt.legend(loc='center left')
plt.axvline(sepsis_onset, color='red', linestyle='dashed')

plt.show()
```

what it currently looks like:
[image: Current Output]

Neither the legend, nor the axvline is currently displayed correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: on which axis do you want to plot?

Answer (score 1):

It was not possible to verify that `sepsis_onset` is actually on your y-axis, but with `subplots=True` the question arises on which of the four plots you actually want the line. `plt.axvline` will not plot to all of them, but calling the function directly on the individual axis objects gives you more control. Conveniently, the `plot()` function returns an array of all axis objects which we need to plot your vertical line in each of the subplots and control its legend location. An example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create some dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=list("ABCD"))
df = df.cumsum()

axes = df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(6, 6));

#Loop over all axis objects and create a vertical line in each of them and set legend location
for ax in axes:
    ax.axvline(400, color='red', linestyle='dashed')
    ax.legend(loc='center left')
```

result:
[image]

Of course you could also the vertical line only to one specific subplot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=list("ABCD"))
df = df.cumsum()

axes = df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(6, 6));
for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(loc='center left')
axes[1].axvline(400, color='red', linestyle='dashed')
```

result:
[image]